# Как сделать не меняющийся обзор камеры в игре из-за смены разрешения?

Tags: unity3d

а) Как сделать так, чтобы в Unity при смене разрешения - не менялась (не отдалялась) камера? (фото 2 и 3)

б) Можно ли сделать, чтобы при смене разрешения, были черные рамки у камеры, создавая разрешение 16:9? То есть при разрешении 4:3, 18:9 и т.д. -- были рамки (сверху и снизу, или по бокам). Как сделано в Brawl Stars, чтобы не было преемущества в обзоре у разных устройств с различным разрешением экрана. (создается 16:9) (На iPad - рамки снизу и сверху - образуется 16:9) [image: Черные рамки для создания 16:9]

[image: Обычное разрешение]
Обзор меняется и увеличивается из-за разрешения
[image: Обзор меняется и увеличивается из-за разрешения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> а) Как сделать так, чтобы в Unity при смене разрешения - не менялась (не отдалялась) камера? (фото 2 и 3)

Сделай скрипт который в зависимости от ширины экрана будет по некоей функции приближать/отдалять камеру.

Например "ВысотаКамерыНадЗемлей = 1 / ШиринаЭкранаВПикселях х КоэфициэнтПодобранныйВручную"

Повесь на камеру и вызывай эту функцию на Start или Awake.

> б) Можно ли сделать, чтобы при смене разрешения, были черные рамки у камеры, создавая разрешение 16:9? То есть при разрешении 4:3, 18:9 и т.д. -- были рамки (сверху и снизу, или по бокам). Как сделано в Brawl Stars, чтобы не было преемущества в обзоре у разных устройств с различным разрешением экрана. (создается 16:9) (На iPad - рамки снизу и сверху - образуется 16:9)

Можно.

1. Расчитываешь соотношение сторон реальное
2. расчитываешь сколько лишних пикселей по ширине и делишь на 2
3. выставляешь значение пункта 2 шириной 2х Image-ей на канвасе которые прикреплены слева и справа экрана.

Answer (score 0):

Получил такой код из ответа выше. Не рекомендую вызывать постоянно просчет (в FixedUpdate), если нет такой необходимости (делайте это в Start или Awake 1 раз). Это работает только с ортографической камерой, в перспективной меняйте параметр "Field Of View".

```
public class CameraRenderer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Camera _camera; // Ваша камера
    [SerializeField] private float _k; // Коэффициент, настроенный вручную

    private void FixedUpdate() // Если нужно постоянное отслеживание 
изменения экрана пользователем
    {
        _camera.orthographicSize = Convert.ToSingle(Screen.height) / 
Screen.width * _k; // Просчет нового размера камеры
    }
}
```

Мой результат при разных разрешениях экрана:
[image: Разрешение 16:9]

[image: Свободное разрешение]